# Centering BS toggle menu when collapsed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am new to BS4 and I couldn't find a answers on how I go about centering the toggle menu when my website is being used on a mobile devices?

[This is an example of what i'm looking to achieve](http://wp.magnium-themes.com/thebuilt/thebuilt-1/our-services/)

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-light">
            <button aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarNav" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>Menu</button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                    </li>




                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="https://spartan-safety-limited.gogecko.com/users/login">TRADE ACCOUNT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!--CAROUSEL-->
</body>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-toggler {

   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: .25rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1;
    background-color: #FF6600 ;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-right: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}


.navbar-light .navbar-toggler{
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: It's `navbar-toggle` not "toggler" you should be targetting I think. (In your HTML and CSS)

Comment: I'm still able to style menu toggle using "toggler"

Comment: Oh, ok. You're running Bootstrap 4 as I've just read. This must be an updated class from v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center this navbar on mobile in the same way that the linked website does, you're going to need to set `display: block`, `margin-left: 0`, and `margin-right: 0` on the `.navbar` and `.navbar-toggler`. All of this sits outside of a media query. Then inside of the media query, we want to set these styles back to its full page view.

This will center the overall `.navbar` in the page and the `.navbar-toggler` button inside of the `.navbar` element.

```css
.navbar-toggler {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: .25rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #FF6600;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-right: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* New styles */

.navbar {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .navbar-toggler {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-light">
    <button aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarNav" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>Menu</button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
        </li>




        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="https://spartan-safety-limited.gogecko.com/users/login">TRADE ACCOUNT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<!--CAROUSEL-->
```

Comment: No problem! Feel free to mark it as the solution if you feel like it solved your problem. This will make it easier for later users to find the solution to the same issue.